# Access Dictionary properties as Object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellisense

I have this classes:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Dictionary<string, Class2>  Items { get; set; }
}


public class Class2
{
    public string Code { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        c.Items = new Dictionary<string, Class2>();

        c.Items.Add("Item0001", new Class2() { Code = "0001", Name = "Item ABC" });
        c.Items.Add("Item0002", new Class2() { Code = "0002", Name = "Item XYZ" });
    }
}
```

What i want to know (i've already googled it but i can't find info about that) is if there is a way to access to the object like this, using the Intellisense or something similar.

```
c.Items.Item0001.Code
```

Comment: From what i know you can't. C# is not EcmaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835420/dictionarystring-string-intellisense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intellisense won't help you in this matter, because your dictionary items are defined in runtime, thus information about this is not available at compile time.

You can however use `ExpandoObject` and `dynamic`;

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.Item0001 = new Class1();
foo.Item0002 = new Class1();

var asDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)foo;
var item1 = asDict["Item0001"];
```